# why is Visual Studio Web App not updating DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Studio web app that i have taken over from an old company employee.

The whole site looks like its split into two parts a main site and a secondary site in a folder within the main site.

The main site seems to update all code when accessed so if i update a .cs file and brows the website it changes.

The secondary site does not do this and has a dll file that is somehow associated with the site.

If i de compile the dll file is gives me the code held in .cs files for all pages.

The problem i have is if i change any code in .cs file and Build the site nothing changes.

I know the site is setup as a web app in VS and have tried Build, Rebuild and publishing to a local folder on local IIS where i am testing everything

If i delete the DLL file then the site refuses to build coming up with multiple errors

As i am fairly new to asp.net and C# i am now at a total loss on what to try next

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: I suppose the cs files are in an `app_code` folder?

Comment: Is there a config file for the secondary site?

Comment: Check the build directories and make sure you're actually rebuilding the DLLs. Typically VS is configured with debug and production build-types that go to different directories. If you build debug, it may not update your production site. Also make sure you have a good backup of your entire production server including the registry before you do this. It's possible to break things and if you don't know what you did, it's going to be difficult to fix.

Comment: i have a web.config file for both sites.
.cs files are in the root folder not in the app_code folder

I only have a debug build-type and no debug or Release folders in the bin folder

i do not know how to check build directories as everything i have found online tells me to go to properties=>build and all i have there is a selection for before running startup page and target framework and some checkboxes so nothing that i can point to a particular folder

Comment: I usually unload the project from the solution and add it back in. That seems to work 80% of the time.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by upload from solution and add it back in?

I am running this locally on IIS at the moment to test and the DLL file is definately not being updated as the modified date is still set to last year

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Clean and rebuild the solution.  If that does not work then try to move the file to a new PC entirely, make the changes you want, clean and build the solution.
You should be fine.

Comment: Tried all that and it was never built on this PC before so doubt moving it would help

Also i do not have an option to clean under the build menu just Build and Rebuild

Comment: Oh okay, I guess the clean option is out because you opened it in visual studio as a website and not as a project. You might want to try that. Anyways, when I had a similar issue, it magically worked and update the dll on a friend's visual studio

Comment: hi how do i open as a project do i need to make new project and add files to it?

Comment: Hi, On Visual Studio, just a the top left corner click "File", then click the "Open" dropdown, you  would see "Project/Solution" click that and go to the directory of your solution/code and open it